# KeyError when trying to fine tuning Bert for text classification

Tags: pytorch, tokenize, bert-language-model, keyerror

I am trying to fine tune Bert for text classification on my dataset and I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Indexing with integers (to access backend Encoding for a given batch index) is not available when using Python based tokenizers'
```

Here is the full error:

```
1/1 * Epoch (train):   0% 0/613 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 47, in <module>
    runner.train(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/runners/runner.py", line 377, in train
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 422, in run
    self._run_event("on_exception")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 365, in _run_event
    getattr(self, event)(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 357, in on_exception
    raise self.exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 419, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 410, in _run
    self.engine.spawn(self._run_local)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/engine.py", line 59, in spawn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 405, in _run_local
    self._run_experiment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 399, in _run_experiment
    self._run_epoch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 391, in _run_epoch
    self._run_loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 384, in _run_loader
    self._run_event("on_batch_start")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 361, in _run_event
    getattr(self, event)(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/runners/supervised.py", line 150, in on_batch_start
    super().on_batch_start(runner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catalyst/core/runner.py", line 321, in on_batch_start
    self.batch_size = len(self.batch[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py", line 241, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: 'Indexing with integers (to access backend Encoding for a given batch index) is not available when using Python based tokenizers'
```

The code I am using for data preparation:

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Mapping, Tuple

import pandas as pd
import torch
from catalyst.utils import set_global_seed
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer


class TextClassificationDataset(Dataset):
    """
    Wrapper around Torch Dataset to perform text classification
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        texts: List[str],
        labels: List[str] = None,
        label_dict: Mapping[str, int] = None,
        max_seq_length: int = 512,
        model_name: str = "GroNLP/hateBERT",
    ):
        """
        Args:
            texts (List[str]): a list with texts to classify or to train the
                classifier on
            labels List[str]: a list with classification labels (optional)
            label_dict (dict): a dictionary mapping class names to class ids,
                to be passed to the validation data (optional)
            max_seq_length (int): maximal sequence length in tokens,
                texts will be stripped to this length
            model_name (str): transformer model name, needed to perform
                appropriate tokenization

        """

        self.texts = texts
        self.labels = labels
        self.label_dict = label_dict
        self.max_seq_length = max_seq_length

        if self.label_dict is None and labels is not None:
            # {'class1': 0, 'class2': 1, 'class3': 2, ...}
            # no easily handle unknown target values
            self.label_dict = dict(zip(sorted(set(labels)), range(len(set(labels)))))

        self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
        # suppresses tokenizer warnings
        logging.getLogger("transformers.tokenization_utils").setLevel(logging.FATAL)

      
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        """
        Returns:
            int: length of the dataset
        """
        return len(self.texts)

    def __getitem__(self, index) -> Mapping[str, torch.Tensor]:
        """Gets element of the dataset

        Args:
            index (int): index of the element in the dataset
        Returns:
            Single element by index
        """

        # encoding the text
        x = self.texts[index]

        # a dictionary with `input_ids` and `attention_mask` as keys
        output_dict = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            x,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            padding="max_length",
            max_length=self.max_seq_length,
            return_tensors="pt",
            truncation=True,
            return_attention_mask=True,
        )


        # for Catalyst, there needs to be a key called features
        output_dict["features"] = output_dict["input_ids"].squeeze(0)
        del output_dict["input_ids"]

        # encoding target
        if self.labels is not None:
            y = self.labels[index]
            y_encoded = torch.Tensor([self.label_dict.get(y, -1)]).long().squeeze(0)
            output_dict["targets"] = y_encoded

        return output_dict
```

What is the problem?

I know questions about similar error have been already asked but they were not of much help in solving this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may want to check [the guide on minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then improve your question accordingly to attract answers.